# Symfony 5 - Get Roles hierarchy to affect them to user

Tags: php, symfony

Using Symfony 5, i've created some roles with hierarchy in "config/packages/security.yaml"
[image: y]

I will create an interface to create/edit/delete roles to users.
So, i want to get all roles existing in the security.yaml, to fill a multiselect or dropdown.

Some instructions found are obsolete, like `$this->container->getParameter('security.role_hierarchy')`.

Have you got a solution to return this data ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `parameter_bag` as follows:

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

/**
 * Class TestController
 * @package App\Controller
 */
class TestController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route(path="test", name="test", methods={"GET"})
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request): Response
    {
        $roles = $this->container->get('parameter_bag')->get('security.role_hierarchy.roles');

        return new Response(json_encode($roles));
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

I think the correct way in Symfony 5 is the following:

```
$hierarchy = $this->container->getParameter('security.role_hierarchy.roles');

$roles = [];
array_walk_recursive($hierarchy, function($role) use (&$roles) {
    $roles[$role] = $role;
});
```

You can access the roles over the `getParameter` function. The old style is not recommended.

If you are in a controller you get call it directly `$this->getParameter`.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunetaly i have the following error : Attempted to call an undefined method named "getParameter" of class "Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Argument\ServiceLocator".

I think "getParameter" is not maintained : https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/service_container/parameters.html

Comment: If you are in a controller you can access it directly with `$this->getParameter`

Comment: I'm migrating to symfony 5.2 $this->container->getParameter not working in controller only $this->getParameter working fine